# Remove duplicate strings Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have two tabs opened in Notepad++.
One contains 450 strings and the other has 180.
How do I remove the 180 which also occur in the list of 450??
I'm aware of find and replace - but how to do this for a batch of 180 strings??

Thank you!

Comment: I would use something like WinMerge for this. http://winmerge.org/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest processing such lists in Excel. It makes operations like subtraction of sets quite comfortable. Steps are:

1. Place 180 strings in column A.
2. Place 450 strings in column B.
3. Put `VLOOKUP()` formula into C1, which searches for value B1 in range A$1:A$180 ($'s must be present!).
4. Double-click dot in bottom-right corner of C1 to spread the formula along the B column.
   **Evaluation is now done:** Values B not present in column A now contain #**N/A**
5. Insert blank row 1 and give columns A,B,C some headers (can be just A, B, C)
6. Press Ctrl+Shift+L to enable filtering (or choose menu `Data`->`Filter`)
7. Click filter in C1 and adjust it to give you only records with #N/A in column C
8. Now copy column B, it contains only filtered values (other rows are hidden).